# Trying to Create New Project But "Unable to Find Library for File" Error When Trying to Run It

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am trying to start a new flutter project; I am a beginner. I created a new project via the command palette in VSC Code and launched the new project from the top bar dropdown. I then made a folder "New Flutter Project." I then simply tried to run the app (I added nothing to it) and see it show up in iOS simulator. But I got this error:

```
Unable to find the library for file:///Users/myname/Desktop/NewFlutterProject/newflutterproject/lib/main.dart
\#0      DartDebugAdapter.evaluateRequest (package:dds/src/dap/adapters/dart.dart:1060:7)
\<asynchronous suspension\>
\#1      BaseDebugAdapter.handle (package:dds/src/dap/base_debug_adapter.dart:141:7)
\<asynchronous suspension\>
```

I then ran flutter doctor on my terminal and it said cocopandas was not properly installed. I had previously installed it so I don't why it was not saying it was not. I then reinstalled homebrew and cocopandas. Then I checked to see if the VSCode issue was resolved and it was not.

I then again tried flutter doctor and the problem got even worse. Now my terminal says:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-US)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/3.2.4/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your
      current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/oliverroberts/development/flutter.
      Consider adding /Users/oliverroberts/development/flutter/bin to the front
      of your path.
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
      more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set path in the system environment variable. This video has a good guide on setting up your environment path before starting using flutter.

Video link here.[check this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f09c-nw15K8)

Because From this flutter doctor i see it's a path issue.

> ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/3.2.4/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your
> current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/oliverroberts/development/flutter.
> Consider adding /Users/oliverroberts/development/flutter/bin to the front
> of your path.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can set flutter and dark SDK path in your system.
First download dart and flutter plugin in your android studio or vs code.

EX:-
1)Open your project in Android Studio and go to Preferences (on Mac) or Settings (on Windows).

2)In the search bar, type "Dart SDK" to find the Dart SDK path setting.

3)Click on "Add..." and navigate to the Flutter SDK directory. ...

4)Click "Apply" to save the settings.

5)Restart Android Studio and try running the example project again.

. then after run this 2 command in terminal to install sdk and android licenses.

```
path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```